# Hydrology - Flowrate vs. radius of influence

Tags: hydrology, groundwater, hydrogeology

I am using the following equation (Theim/Dupuit) to determine radius of influence for an unconfined aquifer. 
[image]

Assume all other variables are held constant. If Q increases, does the Radius of influence R2 also increase?

Comment: Is this homework or for a class? Have you tried rearranging the equation to solve for r2?

Comment: Fred, I apologize if you do not feel this is an earth science question... my question is not about the math...I have rearranged the equation and solved for r2, but it seems that as Q increases, r2 decreases. it is an aquifer drawdown question... If flowrate (Q) is increased, what happens to radius of influence (increase? or decrease?).

Comment: I think your confusion is because you are keeping the head fixed. As you increase Q at fixed T the drawdown curve will become steeper when r1, h1, and h2 are fixed. That means r2 will move towards the pumping well.

Comment: @haresfur can you enter your answer in the box below so this question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion is because you are keeping the head fixed. As you increase Q at fixed T the drawdown curve will become steeper when r1, h1, and h2 are fixed. That means r2 will move towards the pumping well.